# File and folder permissions after changing sqlserver service account

Tags: sql-server

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-2017) article and concluded that the file system permissions needs to be manually set when I change the service account for my SQL server instance.

So I changed the service account for my SQL server instance to a brand new local account via SQL Server Configuration Manager and got surprised that the SQL server service can start, even though I haven't set any file or folder permissions for the new account yet. So the service now runs as the local user, but that user does not have access to the default SQL data folder when I check from Windows. I can also read and write to the default backup folder. Why does it work despite the missing permissions?

Comment: Are you *sure* that user account can't access that folder? The fact that the service is running under that user (if it is), and it is running as normal, then that user **can** access that folder, and any files underneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-2017) article we get the answer:

SQL Server service accounts must have access to resources. Access control lists are set for the **per-service SID** or the **local Windows** group

Answer (score 2):

It works because you used SQL Server Configuration Manager to change the service account. It does all the extra legwork with permissions so that you don't have to.

If, on the other hand, you would use the standard "Services" snap-in found in Control Panel -> Administrative Tools, then nothing would work out of the box, and it would be a truly harrowing experience to set it all up by hand.

Comment: I don't see any new file permissions for the folders in Windows. I only see the old permission for the virtual account. E.g here is what I see via PowerShell:

get-acl 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA' | select -ExpandProperty accesstostring
CREATOR OWNER Allow  FullControl
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
BUILTIN\Administratorer Allow  FullControl
NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER Allow  FullControl

The sql service runs as a new user called localsqluser, but that account hasn't got any permissions on the default data folder.

Comment: or is there a hidden connection to the virtual account NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER

Comment: I'm not sure which folders exactly require such permissions, but I recall that 1) some folders, deep in the SQL Server installation, have permission inheritance disabled (at least for previous versions), and 2) it's not just folders, there are lots of registry keys and (probably) group policies that require permissions / membership as well.

Comment: I just found [this] (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121813/sql-server-virtual-account-and-folder-permissions). and [documentation] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms143504(v=sql.110)#Serv_SID) . the crucial part is this sentence: SQL Server service accounts must have access to resources. Access control lists are set for the per-service SID or the local Windows group

Comment: so the local account is not assigned any folder permission privileges - the whole logic still lies in the virtual account and the way it is linked to the service. But there are of course other stuff and priviliges set for my local account e.g. allow run as a service, etc.